# Is the gradient of $f(x,t)=xe^{t/x}$ w.r.t. ($x,t$) a Lipschitz continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, non-convex-optimization

Consider a function $f(x,t)=xe^{t/x}$ where $C \ge x,t\ge0$ with $C$ being a positive constant. Then, is the gradient $\Delta f$ a Lipschitz continuous function over the domain $[0,C]^2$?

Comment: $f$ does not even have a gradient at $(0,t)$ for $t>0$. (even if you define $f(0,t)$ to be $0$).

Comment: $f(0,t)$ is not defined ! ?